# Перенос программы использующую LocalDB на другие компьютеры

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Знаю, что задавали такой вопрос уже, много информации на эту тему, но у меня к сожалению ничего не получается. Создал приложение Windows Forms с использование локальной базы данных LocalDB. У меня конечно же всё запускается идеально и всё работает, но вот как только перекидываю проект на другой ПК, то БД не подключается, пишет, что "не удалось соединиться с SQL сервером". Нашел интересное видео, где всё подробно и понятно рассказано, сделал всё так же, собрал программу в exe файл с дополнительными пакетами Framework и SQLExpress, что бы они устанавливались, если на клиентской машине нет данного ПО. Всё это прекрасно устанавливается, но не запускается, кто может помочь разобраться с этим, может я что-то не так делаю?

Ссылка на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU9_7ZGG4zg&feature=youtu.be

Это где велась разработка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это где я пытаюсь запустить программу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Сделал, как вы и написали. Создал БД `SqlLocalDB.exe create BDSQLPROJECT 11.0 -s`. БД создана и запущена.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конфиге указал следующее `connectionString="Data
    Source=(LocalDB)\BDSQLPROJECT;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated
    Security=True"` но всё равно выдает ошибку о несовместимости версий.

Comment: у вас БД на этой другой машине установлена? Вы к ней подключиться можете?

Comment: да, БД у меня устанавливается вместе с программой, как и SQL Express, Framework. Нет, подключиться я как раз и не могу, хотя всё установлено.

Comment: Я имею ввиду вообще хоть как то подключиться к кстновленной БД, даже не через вашу программу, а через любую другую. Если подключение не работает, то в этом и есть ваша проблема, тут и копайте, почему оно не работает.

Comment: понял, сейчас попробую

Comment: тут кое-что ещё обнаружил, но не знаю, влияет ли это как-то или нет. Дело в том, что установлены разные версии SQL Serve 2012 Express. На моем ПК 11.1.3000.0, а на другом пк 11.0.2100.60. Это как-то может повлияет на подключение бд?

Comment: скорее всего нужно просто запустить/создать инстанс базы: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Думаю, не повлияет, но было бы неплохо увидеь вашу строку подключения

Comment: @Grundy простите, не особо в этом разбираюсь, но я так понял, нужно будет прописать, что указано в "Examples - A. Creating an Instance of LocalDB"?

Comment: @tym32167 в App.config у меня следующее: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: @CocaineSnow да только с твоим именем MSSQLLocalDB и запустить его

Comment: @Grundy если я всё правильно понял, то должно было получиться что-то типа этого? База создалась и запущена, но моё приложение всё равно выдает ошибку, что не удалось подключиться к SQL Server.   ![Ссылка на изображение](https://ibb.co/2FrgtFD)

Comment: Установил такую же версию SQL Express, что стоит и на моем ПК - не помогло.

Comment: @CocaineSnow, эм... на скрине ты создал Database1, а в connection string  у тебя MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: @Grundy т.е. мне нужно Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; изменить на Data Source=(LocalDB)\Database1?

Comment: @Grundy сделал, как вы и сказали, теперь правда другая ошибка появилась, пишет, что не поддерживаемая версия базы данных (как я понимаю), предлагают просто удалить эту базу и создать новую, тогда якобы создаться БД с нужной версией, но что-то у меня не получается. _the database cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported._

Comment: В ссылке которую я скидывал вроде был пример как выбрать версию.

Comment: @Grundy всё что было написано в той статье я перепробовал, не помогло. Всё равно выдает ошибку о несовместимости версии.

Comment: что выводит команда: `SqlLocalDB.exe versions` на целевом компьютере и на компьютере где велась разработка? Добавь вывод прям в вопрос, для редактирования вопроса можно использовать кнопку [edit].

Comment: @Grundy сделал, как вы и просили.

Comment: в следующий раз лучше текстом прикладывай :)

Comment: ты можешь создать инстанс конкретной версии: `SqlLocalDB.exe create Project11  11.0 -s` - в данном случае 11.

Comment: соответственно я тут указал имя Project11, в connection string  нужно его использовать будет

Comment: ну либо свое имя задать и опять же использовать именно его в connection string

Comment: @Grundy это же тоже самое, что в статье, которую вы скидывали ранее, но всё равно ещё раз проделал, ничего не получилось, более подробно в теме вопроса написал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97381/discussion-between-grundy-and-cocaine-snow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге смог решить проблему и запустить программу с локальной базой данных на другом пк. Последовательность действий была следующая:

1. Создать БД нужной версии и запустить её (на пк, где хотите запустить программу), например: `SqlLocalDB.exe create "MyBD" 11.0 -s`.
2. Меняем параметры в конфиге. Например у вас было `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`, меняем имя БД `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf` на ту, которую создали в п.1, т.е. на `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyBD.mdf`.
3. Пробуем запустить программу.

Лично у меня после этого ничего не запустилось, но зато поменялась ошибка, раньше программа говорила о несовместимости БД или что-то такое, но после манипуляций, которые  я написал выше, ошибка стала следующего характера:

> Database 'C:...\DATABASE1.MDF' cannot be upgraded because it is read-only, has read-only files or the user does not have permission to modify some of the files. Make the database or files writeable, and rerun recovery.

После чего, я удалил программу и установил её заново, но уже поменял путь установки, указал общую (share) папку, например `C:\Users\Public\Setup` и всё, больше никаких настроек или изменений я не делал, просто запустил программу и радовался, БД благополучно подключилась и всё читалось без ошибок.

P.S. Я думаю, что нужно было просто установить программу в общую папку, без всяких там созданий новых БД и т.д., т.к. это вряд ли связано между собой)))