# Перенос приложения с Delphi7 + access на С# + SQL

Tags: c#, sql, delphi, access

*Помимо основного вопроса хотелось бы так же услышать возможные советы по всему процессу реализации задачи. Задание учебное, нет конкретного назначения (само по себе приложение бесполезно, предназначено для практики в учебном заведении).*

Существует малюсенькое приложение на Borland Delphi 7 и такая же небольшая база данных access из 4 таблиц. Была поставлена задача:

1. разместить пару связанных между собой таблиц в DBGrid
2. добавить возможность добавлять/изменять/удалять данные
3. дать возможность переноса приложения по разным ПК
4. хранение данных прямо в корневой папке(имеется ввиду база access)
5. редактировать данные основной таблицы в отдельном окне

С данным заданием проблем не возникло, прикладываю изображение основного окна для понимания.
[image: приложение delphi]

Помимо данной формы присутствует окно приветствия и 2 окна для изменения или добавления данных.
Теперь преподавателем было выдано новое задание, а именно полностью перенести приложение на C# и SQL, написать с нуля новое приложение но с использованием иных инструментов.
С типовыми задачами проблем нет, однако работа с базами данных в C# отличается от Delphi, в связи с чем возник ряд проблем с которыми вот уже 2 дня пытаюсь бороться. Заключаются это проблемы в 3 и 4 пунктах.

Пытался создавать БД напрямую в проекте Visual Studio, использовал SQL Server Management с подключением в виде:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC74\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Smirnov; Integrated Security=True");
```

Подключал при помощи bindingSource и напрямую через dataGridView, ни одно из решений не может быть открыто на другом ПК. Так же при создании БД на сервере нет возможности хранить её в корневой папке приложения. В этом заключаются 2 основные проблемы. Заранее большое спасибо

Добавляю ссылку на скриншоты окон приложения(для наглядности):
[все окна](https://imgur.com/a/TubkdKM)

---

Дополняю вопрос, так как возникли небольшие изменения при разработке и новые трудности.

Извиняюсь за произошедшее недопонимание. Задание было именно с применением SQL запросов.
Сегодня отписался преподаватель и сказал использовать LocalDB при разработке. Согласно новым условиям, я нашел решение проблемы с переносом на разные пк в данном видео https://youtu.be/DU9_7ZGG4zg
ссылаюсь на статью - [Перенос программы использующую LocalDB на другие компьютеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011144/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E-localdb-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Однако поскольку есть необходимость полностью повторить ранее созданное приложение, возникли новые проблемы.
Создал таблицы, перенес их при помощи конструктора из вкладки "Data Source" на форму. Таким же образом на другую форму перенес поля для редактирования, однако столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

1. При открытии новой формы поля заполнены первой строкой, а не той что была выделена.
2. Не имею представления как можно редактировать данные из разных форм.

В вопросе прикреплены изображения того как приложение должно выглядеть, дополню тем как выглядит сейчас в связи с возникшей проблемой.
(в делфи при нажатии на кнопку "редактировать" форма заполняется данными из выделенной строки)
(в c# при нажатии на кнопку "редактировать" форма заполняется данными из первой строки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Access и Sql Server - это две совершенно разных СУБД. Определитесь, с чем именно работаете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в первоначальной работе был использован access, сейчас переписал те же таблицы в sql server, работаю именно с sql

Comment: "перенести приложение на C# и SQL": SQL или MS SQL Server? Сам по себе SQL -- это Structured Query Language, т.е. язык запросов. Например, в Delphi можно работать с MS Access через TADOTable без использования SQL-запросов, а можно через TADOQuery. Из тех БД, с которыми я мало-мальски работал, переносимый режим поддерживают SQLite и Firebird. Но если речь именно о MS SQL Server, возможно, [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420689/6234602) поможет.

Comment: Да, чтобы работать с БД как с файлом, нужен SQL Server Compact. В обычном SQL Server также это возможно (свойство AttachDbFilename в строке соединения), но все равно придется устанавливать движок СУБД на каждый компьютер пользователя, а это далеко не нормальная практика. Тут надо определяться, что вы хотите изучать. Если применение SQL Server в реальных проектах, стоит отходить от принципа "хранить файл в корневой папке" и настраивать настоящий сервер БД, к которому клиенты будут подключаться по сети.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в данный момент меня даже слово "сервер" пугает, до реальных проектов пока далеко

Comment: Дожили, Delphi приложения на C# переносят.

Answer (score 1):

> ни одно из решений не может быть открыто на другом ПК

Проблема в том что приложение не находит сервер.

Нужно:

- установить MS SQL Server (на той же машине что запускается приложение, на другой машине в той же сети)
- создать туже схему базы данных или поднять резервную копию существующей базы
- настроить строку подключения в приложении